# Circle not filled right?

Tags: rendering, mesh

So I am trying to make this circle work and make it viewable but like it not showing up right. I mean I can see it but it looks as if it is stuck in wire frame mode. I'm New to blender so I don't really know my way around in it but I would like it if you could help[image]

Comment: Select one of the loops by holding alt and clicking on it. Then, hold shift and do the same to the other (holding shift holds what you've already selected). Right click, and select "bridge edge loops".

Comment: This question is a duplicate of https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/189898/33589